# Alternative to observablecollection in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, observablecollection

I had a WPF application, where i used ObservableCollection to refresh/change/add to the view from the viewModel with the help of binding.

Now im having additional requirement to create a web application using asp.net mvc

Is there any alternative to ObservableCollection in asp.net mvc?

If so , give a good example with jquery and razor engine(asp.net mvc)..

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. The thing is events are not used in that sense in web development. Probably the closest thing to observable collections would be requesting lists in JSON from server with ajax and render that data clientside. With some clever use of generics, reflections and some javascript you could perhaps turn this code into more dynamic.

Simple example:

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetPersons()
{
      var list = new List<string> { "Jake", "Jenny", "Joe" };
      return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Html:

```
<ul id='personlist'></ul>
```

Jquery:

```
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetPersons", "MyController")',null,
            function (data) {
                // iterate each person from the requested data
                $.each(data, function (i, p) {
                     // render each person as li
                    $("#personlist").append('<li>'+p+'</li>');
                });
            });
```

Another, not so dynamic solution would be just requesting the view, using Viewmodel with list of persons in it.

```
public class PersonsViewModel
{
    public List<string> Persons { get; set; }

    public PersonsViewModel(List<string> persons)
    {
        Persons = persons;
    }
}

public ActionResult Persons()
{
      var list = new List<string> { "Jake", "Jenny", "Joe" };
      return View(new PersonsViewModel(list));
}
```

View:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Persons)
    {
      <li>@item.ToString()</li>
    }
</ul>
```

If you are a newbie with asp.net MVC and been doing WPF/Winforms before my tip is to forget everything you knew about events.

Answer (score 1):

First of all read sormii answer: the lifecycle of a web application does not suit well for this kind of events. You cannot update something on the server (Controller or Razor code) and expect to be refreshed on the client side (HTML) without a round trip.

As sormii suggested use of Ajax calls is the way to proceed. If you like the MVVM pattern and the way that ObservableCollection works, take a look at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.org). With knockoutjs you can declare a javascript viewmodel (don't confuse with a server-side asp.net mvc viewmodel) that contains all data that is displayed in your view. This viewmodel can be updated (using javascript code and ajax calls) and knockoutjs will update the DOM to refresh the values.

This is a small example on how javascript viewmodel will be declared:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.items = ko.observableArray();
   this.items.push({name: 'foo', lastName: 'bar'});
};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Knockout viewmodels are just javascript objects with some of their properties declared as ko.observableArray or ko.observable (ko.observableArray maps ObservableCollection and ko.observable maps a property that raises PropertyChanged event).
Then you need to tell Knockout how to bind this viewmodel to a DOM elements (like using Binding element in WPF and DataTemplate):

```
<li data-bind="foreach: items">
   <ul data-bind="text: name" />
</li>
```

When ko.applyBindings is called, Knockout will create a `<li>` element foreach item in items property of our viewmodel. When items are pushed or deleted from the items property knockout will automatically update the list.

Keep a look at knockoutjs web page as there are a lot of samples and tutorials.